# java swing validate textfield

Tags: java, swing, validation, textfield

I would like to know how I can validate a textfield for blood types.

For example, I have this, but I also need the negative symbol (-). Can somebody can help me?

Example input to validate:

```
A+ B+ AB+ O+ A- B- AB- O-
```

Code I have so far:

```
if(txtSangre.matches("(A|B|AB|O)\\+")==false){    
    mensaje("Ingresar un grupo sanguineo");
}
```

Comment: Aren't these blood types?

Comment: `validated a textfield for DNA` Those look like blood types, not DNA...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While you did a pretty good job of asking your question in English, some of your code is in Spanish. You should translate so the English only readers can  help you. The phrase "grupo sanguineo" translates to blood type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to match one blood type, try this:

```
if (txtSangre.matches("(A|B|AB|O)(\\+|-)") == false) {    
    mensaje("Ingresar un grupo sanguineo");
}
```

It will match text A, B, AB, or O followed by either a plus (+) or a minus (-).

If you're looking to match a whole line of data separated by spaces as given in your question, use this regex pattern instead:

```
if (txtSangre.matches("^(\\s?(A|B|AB|O)(\\+|-)\\s?)+$") == false) {    
    mensaje("Ingresar un grupo sanguineo");
}
```